# In the given figure find $PT$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

In the given figure $\angle Q=\angle R=\angle S=90^\circ,\;PQ=QR=5,\;RS=10,\;ST=3$ then the length of $PT$ will be:

Comment: Lots of similar right triangles in the shape

Comment: Can You Please Give Me The Solution... 

Answer (score 2):

It is only the Pythagoras theorem:
[image]

Comment: It will be 15² + 8² . AT is 8 cm... Thanks BTW it was a easy question but my mind was not working... Thanks a lot...